# Is AWS SNS required for Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have a production server running an application and also a mobile app for the same, I want to use FCM as my push notification service , but what I'm seeing from the google website and most stack overflow answers is somewhat conflicting. Stack has a lot of answers on how to get FCM running on SNS, I want to know is it possible to simply use FCM (as its free) or would I need SNS , if not why bother setting up SNS for FCM? Keep in mind I only want to use FCM through an API for a django server and not through the firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase documentation is clear on how to get started, and nowhere does it state that SNS is required.  Just follow the documentation for your client app platform.

If you want to send messages from your AWS backend, you can just use the Firebase Admin SDK for your chosen backend OS.  It will also not require SNS.

If you are having a specific problem with FCM, you should ask a new question explaining what you've done so far that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your code and links to the documentation you're working with.

Comment: can u tell me why using sns would be beneficial if at all?

Comment: If you have a new question, post it separately. Be sure to first read the documentation, then explain where you are stuck with what you are trying to accomplish.